# how can i give a target blank on the specific href tag in my navigation jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, target

i will to give a specific outside link in my navigation with target blank. How can i solve this with jQuery ?

Here my Site:

http://devel.hoevermann-gruppe.de/

If you click `auf "Kontakt" in the head navigation you see the mega sub menuand if you click on Facebook, so the outside started in the same window tab but i will use the target blank tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$('a[href*="www.facebook.com"]').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: hey,but if i click on my facebook link so the window location are in the same window and i will to show in a new tab

Comment: I fixed an error, quotes are needed around www.facebook.com. I just tried it on your site, it opened the link in a new tab.

Comment: you set quotes so: $('a[href="https://www.facebook.com/"]').attr('target', '_blank');

Comment: You have an extra `;` after `'target'`.

Comment: no the editor make this here if you look in my basic.js on my site you can see that i don't have it

Comment: You need to do it inside the `$(document).ready()` handler, because you load `basic.js` before the DOM is ready.